# Не работает "Open With" на андроид при открытом приложении

Tags: java, android

У меня есть приложение - текстовый редактор, мной написанное на java. Сделал, чтобы при открытии в андроид файла через open with и выборе данного приложения текст этого файла отображался в приложении.
Проблема в том, что приложение ничего не показывает, если оно уже было открыто.
Что делать?
В манифесте прописал:

````
android:name=".MainActivity">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name = "android.intent.action.VIEW" />
<category android:name = "android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<data
android:mimeType = "text/*"
android:scheme = "content" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>```
````

Comment: Покажите код активити

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Поэкспериментировав нашёл, что всё дело в `singleTask` в манифесте:

```
<activity
android:name=".MainActivity"
android:launchMode="singleTask">
</activity>
```

Отчего я узнал, что нужно добавить в класс MainActivity:

```
@Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent intt) {
    readOpenWith(intt);
}
```